# Scrape an image from website in Google sheets (using ImportXml)

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape a product image from Aliexpress website to display in a cell together with link and other details. I've been trying to formulate the xpath, however I've been getting an error.
this is the command I've used:

```
=image(IMPORTXML(A2, "(//img[@class='magnifier-image'])[1]/@src"))
```

A2 is the product link

[this is the element from Aliexpress website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujTZE.png)

link to the product: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001845596088.html

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong please?
I would be very grateful for any ideas.
Thank you,
Kristyna

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the HTML data retrieved by `IMPORTXML` has not value of `img[@class='magnifier-image']`. But, fortunately, that image URL can be retrieved from `meta` tag. When this is reflected in the formula, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMAGE(IMPORTXML(A2,"//meta[@property='og:image']/@content"))
```

- The cell "A2" has the URL of `https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001845596088.html`.
- In this case, the image URL of `https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S962937cf821a4e0196a11cf0c877df11Y/Birthday-Valentine-Day-Keychain-Gifts-for-Boyfriend-Husband-My-Man-I-love-you-Couples-Keyring-for.jpg` is retrieved.

#### Note:

- This sample formula is for the URL of `https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001845596088.html`. So when you change the URL, this formula might not be able to be used. And also, when the specification of the site is changed, this formula might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, 
Thank you so much for your reply, I'm amazed! It works like magic! Thank you so much! Can I please ask you for to incorporate custom height and width of the image into the formula? It's very small picture.

Comment: @Kristyna Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Can I please ask you for to incorporate custom height and width of the image into the formula? It's very small picture.`, in this case, the image size depends on the cell size. So even when you use [the option of `IMAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333), the cell size cannot be changed. If you want to change the image size, please change the cell size.